# is there any way to edit scope key in AAD login in backstage.?

Tags: backstage

I have a backstage instance in which i am using AAD login in which backstage is passing some scope like "user.read offline_access etc" value, i want to add few more keys like "Clendar.ReadWrite". is there any way to do that in backstage.

I am trying to pass ./default values in scope key. I have searched a lot for possible solutions but couldn't get any of it

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't get it wrong, do you want to transform the values ​​created for the `User` entity?

This [documentation](https://backstage.io/docs/integrations/azure/org#customizing-transformation) may help, if applicable.

The following provides an example of each kind of transformer

```js
import * as MicrosoftGraph from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types';
import {
  defaultGroupTransformer,
  defaultUserTransformer,
  defaultOrganizationTransformer,
} from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend-module-msgraph';
import { GroupEntity, UserEntity } from '@backstage/catalog-model';

// This group transformer completely replaces the built in logic with custom logic.
export async function myGroupTransformer(
  group: MicrosoftGraph.Group,
  groupPhoto?: string,
): Promise<GroupEntity | undefined> {
  return {
    apiVersion: 'backstage.io/v1alpha1',
    kind: 'Group',
    metadata: {
      name: group.id!,
      annotations: {},
    },
    spec: {
      type: 'aad',
      children: [],
    },
  };
}

// This user transformer makes use of the built in logic, but also sets the description field
export async function myUserTransformer(
  graphUser: MicrosoftGraph.User,
  userPhoto?: string,
): Promise<UserEntity | undefined> {
  const backstageUser = await defaultUserTransformer(graphUser, userPhoto);

  if (backstageUser) {
    backstageUser.metadata.description = 'Loaded from Azure Active Directory';
  }

  return backstageUser;
}

// Example organization transformer that removes the organization group completely
export async function myOrganizationTransformer(
  graphOrganization: MicrosoftGraph.Organization,
): Promise<GroupEntity | undefined> {
  return undefined;
}
```